# Dividing a column using a pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that has a table with an item ID assigned to a category and subcategory divided by a dot (please refer to the inserted link below). I need, if it is possible, to divide the column category.subcategory into 2 columns: category and subcategory like in the image. Is it possible to do that?

[image]

Basically I want to convert this:

```
Item ID     Category.Subcategory
2526        CategoryA.SubcategoryB
2527        CategoryC.SubcategoryD
```

Into this, preserving the ID and its corresponding category and subcategory

```
Item ID    Category     Subcategory
2526       CategoryA    SubcategoryB
2527       CategoryC    SubcategoryD
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show your code, what did you try so far?

Comment: It's a good idea to clean up your data thus. You are looking for string manipulation, so google `MySQL string functions` and you get here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html. There you find `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, which is the function you need.

Comment: Thanks @Hokascha . I have never worked with a database before. At this moment I know that it is a MySQL database and I'm trying to learn how to use phpMyAdmin. I know basically nothing about MySQL. Sorry, I haven't tried that much. I was searching but I supposed it was better to ask directly about my specific case.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner I will take a look at that documentation.

Comment: Google Mysql how to split string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the Query below :**

```
select `Item ID`, substring_index(Category.Subcategory,'.',1) as Category,
substring_index(Category.Subcategory,'.',-1) as Subcategory 
from YourTable;
```

It uses `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`  function which returns the substring from the given string before a specified number of occurrences of a delimiter.

`-1`  returns the substring from the right of the final delimiter (1st delimiter)

syntax is : `SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)`

Comment: Worth noting, for final delimiter to be the same as first delimiter, there must only be one of the delimiter character in the string.

Comment: Yes , It counts the delimiter you mentioned in the query

Comment: Thank you @ShivYadav !!! It just worked perfectly at the first try. Now I have the two columns that I want. Thanks again!